# How to connect an sqlamp module to a Flask-SQLAlchemy session?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

Here is [sqlamp docs](http://sqlamp.angri.ru).
I don't understand how I can connect sqlamp with predefined flask-sqlalchemy session. [Docs](http://pythonhosted.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/api.html) says something like

```
from history_meta import VersionedMeta, VersionedListener

app = Flask(__name__)
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_extensions=[VersionedListener()])

class User(db.Model):
    __metaclass__ = VersionedMeta
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True)
    pw_hash = db.Column(db.String(80))
```

but there is no `session_extensions` in the latest version of flask-sqlalchemy. Maybe I've got to use a `session_options`, but it is unclear how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Slightly different syntax now:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(session_options={'extension': [VersionExtension()]})
```